# Cannot download "BIG" data (normal size satellite imagery) from Google Earth Engine with Python

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to download Sentinel-2 Imagery through Python, yet it does not even allow me to download a single band. For instance, NIR (B8) band to its native resolution (10m) because it says that it is too big.

Also, I tried to download a multispectral image with all the bands, yet it only allows me to download imagery with 70 m spatial resolution. I tried to download NIR band so I can pan-sharpen with the multispectral image.

Apart from cropping to a smaller image so I can download images, is there another way to download full sized images with their native resolution?

Here is my code.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep 28 14:19:15 2021

@author: karas
"""

import ee
import geemap
import os
import argparse


def filtering(dataset, sdate, edate, aoi, cloud):
    # # Area of Interest
    # aoi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([int(aoi[0]), int(aoi[1]), int(aoi[2]), int(aoi[3])])
    aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(float(aoi[0]), float(aoi[1]))
    # aoi = ee.Geometry.Point(aoi[0], aoii[1])
    # Getting the dataset
    dataset = ee.ImageCollection(dataset)\
        .filterDate(sdate, edate)\
        .filterBounds(aoi)\
        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloud))\
        .limit(10)

    return dataset

# Initialize the library.
ee.Initialize()

# Creating the arguments 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Downloading parameters')
parser.add_argument('--dataset', type = str,
                    help = 'Dataset to be used')
parser.add_argument('--sdate', type = str,
                    help = 'Start date')
parser.add_argument('--edate', type = str,
                    help = 'End date')
parser.add_argument('--aoi', nargs = '+',
                    help = 'Area of Interest with geographical coordinates')
parser.add_argument('--out_path', type = str,
                    help = 'Path to save images')
parser.add_argument('--cloud_cov', type = int,
                    help = 'Cloud coverage')
args = parser.parse_args()

# Creating a list of bands
bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12']

# Getting the dataset
dataset = filtering(args.dataset,
                    args.sdate,
                    args.edate,
                    args.aoi,
                    # rectROI,
                    args.cloud_cov).select(bands)

# Getting the projection
# projection = dataset.first().select(1).projection()

# Saving the Images
geemap.ee_export_image_collection(dataset,
                                  args.out_path,
                                  crs = 'EPSG:32634',
                                  scale = 70,
                                  file_per_band = False
                                  # region = 
                                  )

geemap.ee_export_image_collection(dataset.select('B8'),
                                  args.out_path,
                                  crs = 'EPSG:32634',
                                  scale = 25,
                                  file_per_band =True
                                  # region = 
                                  )
```

Comment: You don't specify the `aoi` in your supplied code, so it is not possible to know what size area you are trying to download. It is not clear what you mean by 'normal size satellite imagery'. Are you referring to a single granule?

Comment: The native resolution of Sentinel 2 Band 8 NIR (as well as the blue, green and red bands 2, 3 & 4) is 10m, not 15m. You don't pan-sharpen with NIR, you pan-sharpen with the *pan*chromatic band.  And S2 doesn't have a pan band.  Are you thinking of Landsat-8 band 8 which is a pan band with 15m resolution?

Comment: @Matt yes I am talking about a single granule, that's why I did not specify the region in the **ee_export_image_collection**. I just want an entire image that sentinel-2 can capture but google earth engine does not allow me to do that probably due to scaling issues.

Comment: @user2856 You are right. The resolution of NIR band in Sentinel-2 is 10m. Yet based on [this](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3900/2/7/345), as far as sentinel-2 is concerned, bands in visible or nir spectrum can be used as panchromatic. But I cannot even download a single band in its native resolution. May I tile the entire image somehow in order to obtain it without scaling problems?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the solution for downloading images in their initial resolution. Google Earth Engine is a provider for the Sentinel-2 mission, yet in order to fulfill all the requests for downloading, GEE decreases the resolution of the images. As an alternative, I used the *sentinelsat* python library which with few lines of code, one is able to download images from Sentinel missions to their full resolution. More info can be found [here](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)